# Getting imagick to work with php 5.6

Tags: php

After searches and reboots, i finally got imagemagick installed. phpinfo() shows it as working and supports 150 formats while system("convert -version"); gives the correct delegates installed "bzlib cairo freetype jbig jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr pangocairo png ps rsvg tiff webp xml zlib".

When starting Apache, no error messages are displayed. Yet when I tried this:

```
 $image = new Imagick($source);
 $image->thumbnailImage($maxWidth, $maxHeight);
 $image->writeImage($fileName);
 $image->destroy();
```

I get error messages "Message: unable to load module `C:\ImageMagick\IM_MOD_RL_JPEG_.dll': The specified procedure couldnt be found.

I did check the dll file exists in C:\imagemagick. I am on a threadsafe PHP 5.6, X86 architecture, Windows 7 with VC11.

Update:

Just tried with gif image, it works fine. It founds RL_GIF_.dll yet they are on the same folders. whats happening please?

Comment: I assume you know your code is for the Imagick API and not Imagemagick via the command line?

Comment: @Bonzo yes...it was part of PHP. Command line works fine. PHP echo system("convert -version") shows delegates jpeg,php etc and phpinfo() I do see the line: imagick classes  Imagick, ImagickDraw, ImagickPixel, ImagickPixelIterator